# Laptop freezes with power when trying to suspend or hibernate (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, suspend, hibernate

I am a Linux newbie, I researched my issue quite a bit in the last few weeks but have not managed to solve it.

When I try to suspend my laptop, either by pressing the power button or closing the lid, most of the times it will freeze:

- Power led remains on
- Screen off.
- Nothing happens when typing or clicking mouse buttons.

The only option in this state is hard shutdown (long press power button).

This happens *most* of the times I tried to suspend.
I discovered that when clicking the "pause" icon in the lock screen, suspend mode does work as expected, but not always (sometimes it freezes).

I also ran `pm-suspend`. It, too, results in the same freeze state, but it produces a crash report in `/var/crash`. The file is quite long so I'm not copying it into the question. From what I can tell, the file doesn't indicate any specific issues that I can focus on. `pm-hibernate` also crashes, in the same way.

The only piece of nonstandard hardware on this laptop is a cellular modem, which doesn't ship in the standard version.

Any help would be appreciated.

- Laptop: Dell Latitude 5590
- Processor: Intel(R) Core i7-8650U
- Graphics: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
- Kernel: 5.4.5-050405-generic (upgraded by me using UKUU)

Comment: Does it do it with either supported Ubuntu kernel for 18.04?  (ie. 4.15 *GA* or 5.3 *HWE*)

Comment: @guiverc Yes, it was the same with 4.15. I upgraded the kernel in hope the newer kernel would solve it

Comment: FYI: If it was me, I'd have just switched to the HWE kernel (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), and if you wanted to try the 5.4 kernel I'd have booted a 'live' Ubuntu 20.04 daily ISO & explore using that; as the 5.3 HWE kernel will upgrade to 20.04's anyway & has security covered full life of 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0):

This was a hardware issue. After replacing the motherboard (under warranty) the issue is gone. Hopefully this might help someone with similar issues - sometimes the OS and bundled software is not at fault.

Comment: Interesting, I have the same (or very similar) board. It's always been unpredictable, but since ubuntu 18 will not suspend or hibernate. It still sleeps fine from the Original windows 10 partition though.